# Low compression and will not ignite after broken camshaft pin and replaced head and gasket

Tags: engine, compression, head-gasket

My 95 Geo Metro Lsi 1.0L had a blown head gasket. I replaced the gasket and drove the car for approximately 120 miles before it started spitting and sputtering. Then it died just before I got home. I pushed the car home and started taking it apart.

I found out that the camshaft pin that fits in the cam gear had broken, and the timing jumped like crazy. I checked the bottom end out and everything looks okay. It rolls over easily, and there is no metal in the oil. I ordered a new head and upper engine gasket kit.

I got the whole thing back together, and tried to start the engine, but it just turns over -- "does not try to start at all". I checked the compression and it was 75 psi across the board. After I did the first head gasket, I had 175 psi across all 3 cylinders.

I am wondering if I have my timing wrong and if that can cause low compression. I also put some oil in each cylinder and let it sit for 10 minutes, then did another compression test; it jumped up to 100 psi. My pistons don't look cracked and they hold diesel fuel with no leakdown overnight.

What could be causing these problems?

Comment: Who ever changed my wording needs to change it back. I do not agree with how you have reworded what i wrote.

Comment: If you're seeing 75 psi, I doubt the timing is horribly wrong. When my timing belt slipped, I had no compression at all and the engine turned freely with almost no resistance. I suppose it's possible that you're just off by a few notches, but I'd look for other causes...

Comment: The original form of your question was riddled with bad grammar and had a title that provided no useful information about the contents of the question. I didn't change the content, I just made it clear. Please see http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/editing and  maybe [Can I prevent others from editing my question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28005) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how bad your timing was off you may have bent your valves in the heads causing poor seating and bad compression.

Also maybe your timing is still off.

Comment: I order a new head thinking it was the problem. Installed it and took the old head to get it checked. The head was slightly warped. i had them surface it and install new valvestem seals. so atleast i have an extra head now. I do still think my timing is off but i put #1 at TDC and line up my timing marks. I will take it back apart this weekend and triple check everything again. Thanks for the reply